# Can't map DropDownListFor html helper with model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code may seem a little weird, but it is educational so I think it is acceptable:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var residents = await _residentAccountService.GetResidentAccounts();

        var viewModel = new AddRealEstateViewModel
        {
            Residents = residents.Select(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.FamilyName).ToList()
        };

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (string accountNames in viewModel.Residents)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = $"{accountNames}", Value = $"{accountNames}" });
        }

        SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Text");
        ViewBag.Zb = selectList;

        ModelState.Clear();

        return View("CreateRealEstateView", viewModel);
    }
```

Inside the action I am trying to access to data about Residents through my fellow's service, and then transfer this to view as `SelectListItem` for `DropDownListFor`.

Here how it looks in the view:

```
<select asp-for="ResidentAccount" asp-items= "@Html.DropDownListFor((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Model.Residents, ViewBag.Zb, "Set the Owner", new { @class = "foo"})" class="form-control"></select>
```

I get this error:

> RuntimeBinderException: The type arguments for method 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<UtopiaCity.ViewModels.HousingSystem.AddRealEstateViewModel>.DropDownListFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<UtopiaCity.ViewModels.HousingSystem.AddRealEstateViewModel,TResult>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>, string, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
> CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IHtmlHelper , IEnumerable , object , string , <>f__AnonymousType0 )
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, TRet>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
> AspNetCore.Views_HousingSystem_CreateRealEstateView.b__26_0() in CreateRealEstateView.cshtml
> +
> "@Html.DropDownListFor((IEnumerable)Model.Residents, ViewBag.Zb, "Set the Owner", new { @class = "foo"})"
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)

I don't know what I am doing wrong there is no compile error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem> {Value="0", Text="Set the Owner"};

 foreach (string accountNames in viewModel.Residents)
 {
items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = $"{accountNames}", Value = $"{accountNames}" });
}

  ViewBag.SelectList = items;
```

and view

```
<select asp-for="ResidentAccount" asp-items= "@ViewBag.Selectlist", new { @class = "foo"})" class="form-control"></select>
```